# Hide the term description on the term edit page, for a given taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy, forms, terms

I have written some long descriptions for a custom category taxonomy. I don't want to remove them, I just want to hide it from the management page:

```
/wp-admin/term.php?taxonomy=custom_category
```

I could use CSS to hide the class "column-description", but I don't know how to only apply it to this taxonomy.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could target the edit form for the *post_tag* taxonomy, through the `post_tag_edit_form` hook:

```
/**
 * Hide the term description in the post_tag edit form
 */
add_action( "post_tag_edit_form", function( $tag, $taxonomy )
{ 
    ?><style>.term-description-wrap{display:none;}</style><?php
}, 10, 2 );
```

Here you can also target an individual tag.

If you need something similar for other taxonomies, you can use the `{taxonomy_slug}_edit_form` hook.

### Update

It looks like the question was about the list tables, not the edit form.

I dug into the list tables in WorPress and found a way to remove the description column from the term table in `edit-tags.php`

```
/**
 * Remove the 'description' column from the table in 'edit-tags.php'
 * but only for the 'post_tag' taxonomy
 */
add_filter('manage_edit-post_tag_columns', function ( $columns ) 
{
    if( isset( $columns['description'] ) )
        unset( $columns['description'] );   

    return $columns;
} );
```

If you want to do the same for other taxonomies, use the `manage_edit-{taxonomy_slug}_columns` filter.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Wasnt quite what i wanted, but it lit the lightbulb on what i needed to do. I wanted to hide the column from the list of categories. i.e. when you click the post type and then the drop down shows "categories" i wanted to hide the description from this page. used the _add_form_fields hook instead and used the css rule there

Comment: I updated the answer with a way to remove the 'description' column from the term table. Hopefully I understand this correctly now, if so please correct my previous edits to your question ;-) @DanHastings

Answer (score 8):

The cleanest way to do that, removing the description field from the edit screen also in the add screen:

```
function hide_description_row() {
    echo "<style> .term-description-wrap { display:none; } </style>";
}

add_action( "{taxonomy_slug}_edit_form", 'hide_description_row');
add_action( "{taxonomy_slug}_add_form", 'hide_description_row');
```

Of course you need to replace {taxonomy_slug} with your taxonomy slug.

Comment: Should be marked as the accepted answer.

Comment: This is a good answer for hiding the description edit field, but most use cases will probably include hiding the column as well using the `manage_edit-{taxonomy_slug}_columns` filter.

Comment: As far as I see this, this will result in invalid HTML because of the style tags outside of the <head>. See my proposed solution.

Answer (score 4):

If you also need to hide the description field in the add form use this code

```
/**
 * Hide the term description in the edit form
 */
add_action( '{taxonomy_slug}_add_form', function( $taxonomy )
{
    ?><style>.term-description-wrap{display:none;}</style><?php
}, 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

I would propose another solution.

```php
function add_custom_taxonomy_css()
{
  wp_enqueue_style(
    "custom-taxonomy",
    get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . "/custom-taxonomy.css"
  );
}

add_action("exhibitions_edit_form", "add_custom_taxonomy_css");
add_action("exhibitions_add_form", "add_custom_taxonomy_css");
```

and
`custom-taxonomy.css`

```css
/*
 * hiding taxonomy description
 */

.term-description-wrap {
  display: none;
}
```

This has, in contrast to the other solution, the advantage, that we still get valid HTML, because we have no stray `<style>` tags within our `<body>`.