# Remove standard meta boxes from custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, functions, custom-taxonomy

[image]I registered a custom post type, and then registered a taxonomy to show on the custom post type. When clicking on the taxonomy entry on the post type, I see the edit screen with various native boxes, aka:

```
Name
Slug
Parent Item
Description
```

Since I will use ACF exclusively, there is no need to display the description box, or Parent Item box.

Is there a way to remove them? (without using the css display property)

Thank you for any pointers.

Comment: ["Remove description in custom taxonomy edit screen"](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/288381/remove-description-in-custom-taxonomy-edit-screen), ["Hide the term description on edit page"](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/217932/hide-the-term-description-on-the-term-edit-page-for-a-given-taxonomy)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not. These items are hard-coded into the `wp-admin/edit-tags.php` file. The best route is the route you didn't want to go which is CSS.

You can replace `category` in the below array with a list of taxonomies you want to apply these styles to. The function checks the current taxonomy against this array and if it's found will apply the CSS styles to hide these fields.

```
/**
 * Hide taxonomy fields per taxonomy
 *
 * @return void
 */
function wpse344725_taxonomy_css() {

    global $taxonomy;

    $modified_tax_arr = array( 'category' );

    if( empty( $taxonomy ) || ! in_array( $taxonomy, $modified_tax_arr ) ) {
        return;
    }

    ?>

        <style>
            .form-field.term-slug-wrap,
            .form-field.term-parent-wrap,
            .form-field.term-description-wrap   {display: none;}
        </style>

    <?php

}
add_action( 'admin_head', 'wpse344725_taxonomy_css' );
```

Additionally, with the above method you could remove them with JavaScript or hide them with any other CSS visibility property. I can't think of a reason why you wouldn't want to simply hide them in CSS maybe with more elaboration we can find a better solution.

Comment: On my custom taxonomy I have a bunch of fields with instructions on how to properly fill them out. With the WP native fields on the taxonomy the user has the potential to get confused and enter incorrect format/information. I need to hide the field specifically on that page only. It looks like your snippet will hide them on all applicable pages? Also, your above snippet doesn't hide the field, unfortunately.

Comment: I added a screenshot to the original post. I want to remove the Parent Issue box, and the Description box.

Comment: Your solution worked, had to switch out `category` with my taxonomy's name.

Comment: @Hewe you can add multiple taxonomies to that array, it checks the current taxonomy against that array and if it's in the array it will apply the below styles. I don't think you can get away from keeping `Name` a shown field. It's a required field for the form.